# Resource for intermolecular forces in soft condensed matter

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-matter

I need a book dealing in particular with the intermolecular forces and, if possible, the diffusive processes. Someone knows an appropriate one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Intermolecular and Surface Forces" by Jacob Israelachvili.  A new edition came out recently.  This covers all the types of forces relevant at the molecular scale or nanoscale.