# Resource recommendations

Tags: resource-recommendations, faq

Every once in a while, we get a question asking for a book or other educational reference on a particular topic at a particular level. This is a meta-question that collects all those links together. If you're looking for book recommendations, this is probably the place to start.

All the questions linked below, as well as others which deal with more specialized books, can be found under the tag [resource-recommendations](/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) (formerly [books](/questions/tagged/books)).

If you have a question to add, please edit it in. However, make sure of a few things first:

1. The question should be tagged [resource-recommendations](/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations)
2. It should be of the form "What are good books to learn/study [subject] at [level]?"
3. It shouldn't duplicate a topic and level that's already on the list

**Related Meta:** [Do we need/want an overarching books question?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5307/23119)

Answer (score 296):

**Broad Interest**

- [Please recommend a good book about physics for young child (elementary school aged)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21849)
- [Books that develop interest & critical thinking among high school students](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/893)
- [Books that every layman should read](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13020)
- [Books that every physicist should read](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/884)
- [A good highschool level physics book](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352424)
- [Are there modern 1st year university physics textbooks using old-schoool layout, i.e. no sidebars and smaller format?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/399225)

**Mathematics**

- *General*: [Best books for mathematical background?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193/)
- *Basic methods*: [Book recommendations for Fourier Series, Dirac Delta Function and Differential Equations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/518442)
- *Tensors*: [Learn about tensors for physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386103)
- *Complex analysis*: [Complex Variable Book Suggestion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/359286)
- *Group theory*: [Comprehensive book on group theory for physicists?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6108)
- *Spectral theory*: [Books for linear operator and spectral theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/598)
- *Variational calculus*: [Introductory texts for functionals and calculus of variation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7737)
- *Geometry and topology*: [Book covering differential geometry and topology for physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29956)
- *Algebraic geometry*: [Crash course on algebraic geometry with view to applications in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2528)
- *Dynamical systems/chaos*: [Self-study book for dynamical systems theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353841)
- *Fractals*: [Physics-oriented books on fractals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12784)
- *Distribution theory*: [Resources for theory of distributions (generalized functions) for physicists](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127376)
- *Statistics*: [Rigorous error analysis theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299339)

**Mechanics**

- *Introductory*: [Recommendations for good Newtonian mechanics and kinematics books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6068)
- *Introductory (for mathematicians)*: [Which Mechanics book is the best for beginner in math major?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9165)
- *Foundations*: [Book suggestions for foundation of Newtonian Mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12964)
- *Lagrangian and Hamiltonian*: [Any good resources for Lagrangian and Hamiltonian Dynamics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135726)
- *Advanced/geometrical*: [Book about classical mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111)
- *Fully geometrical*: [Classical mechanics without coordinates book](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1601)

**Classical Field Theories**

- *Electromagnetism (advanced undergraduate)*: [Recommended books for advanced undergraduate electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142419)
- *Electromagnetism (graduate)*: [Graduate level book in classical electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571571)
- *Electromagnetism (with applications)*: [Electrodynamics textbooks that emphasize applications](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20752)
- *Waves*: [What's a good textbook to learn about waves and oscillations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15970)
- *General*: [Need for a side book for E. Soper's Classical Theory Of Fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45941)
- *Elasticity*: [Modern references for continuum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2687)
- *Fluid dynamics*: [Book recommendations for fluid dynamics self-study](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71257)
- *Boundary layer theory*: [Boundary layer theory in fluids learning resources](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9815)

**Special Relativity**

- *Introductory*: [What are good books for special relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/325828)
- *Visual*: [Textbook for special relativity: modern version of Bondi's Relativity and Common Sense?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/151505)
- *Geometric*: [Textbook on the Geometry of Special Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95609/)
- *Math-free*: [Recommended books for a "relativity for poets" class?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143238)
- *Relativistic imaging*: [Reference request for relativistic imaging](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229282)

**Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics**

- *Short*: [Crash course in classical thermodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36288)
- *Undergraduate statistical mechanics*: [Good undergraduate statistical mechanics textbook](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/724939/)
- *Advanced*: [Recommendations for statistical mechanics book](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30550)
- *Careful*: [References about rigorous thermodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5614)
- *Foundational*: [Are there any modern textbooks on statistical mechanics which don't ignore Gibbs' analysis of the microcanonical ensemble?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76145)
- *Differential forms*: [Introduction to differential forms in thermodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32296)
- *Stochastic processes*: [Suggestion on good stochastic processes book for self-teaching](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301579)
- *Quantum statistical mechanics*: [Resources for introductory quantum statistical mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177539)
- *Complex systems*: [What are some of the best books on complex systems and emergence?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39712)
- *Information Theoretic Point of View*: [Reference for statistical mechanics from information theoretic view](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233180/)

**Astrophysics and Cosmology**

- *Popular*: [Recommend good book(s) about the "scientific method" as it relates to astronomy/astrophysics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25030)
- *Astronomy*: [What is a good introductory text to astronomy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25512)
- *Astrophysics*: [What are good books for graduates/undergraduates in Astrophysics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44882)
- *Cosmology (introductory)*: [Books on cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159120)
- *Dark matter/dark energy*: [Dark matter and dark energy references](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5613)
- *Inflation*: [Good resources for understanding inflationary cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277898)
- *Neutrinos*: [Book suggestion about Neutrino effect on Cosmic Structure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525186)

**Quantum Mechanics**

- *Popular*: [Looking for a good casual book on quantum physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/314714)
- *Historical*: [Good book on the history of Quantum Mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18632)
- *Introductory*: [What is a good introductory book on quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215)
- *Advanced*: [Learn QM algebraic formulations and interpretations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14377)
- *Mathematical*: [A book on quantum mechanics supported by the high-level mathematics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22409)
- *Path integral*: [Path integral formulation of quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19417)
- *Decoherence*: [Decoherence and quantum to classical limit: good resources?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/548536)
- *Berry phase*: [Book on Berry phase and its relation to topology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257605)
- *Interpretations*: [Books about alternative interpretations of quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112968)

**Atomic, Molecular, Optical Physics**

- *High school optics*: [Where is a good place to learn classical optics for high school competitions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21288)
- *Atomic and molecular*: [Book recommendation for Atomic & Molecular physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167562)
- *Open systems*: [Book recommendations for learning about open quantum systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/367004)
- *Quantum information*: [Quantum information references](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20260)
- *Quantum cryptography*: [A good book for Quantum Cryptography](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106168)
- *Quantum optics*: [Book Recommendation: Quantum optics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262850)

**Condensed Matter**

- *Introductory/solid state*: [Intro to Solid State Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105144)
- *Advanced*: [Books for Condensed Matter after Ashcroft/Mermin](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22046)
- *Second quantization*: [Book recommendations for second quantization](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72335)
- *Mathematically rigorous*: [Mathematical rigorous introduction to solid state physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27637)
- *Anyons*: [References on the physics of anyons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6839)
- *Fractional statistics*: [Resource recommendation for fractional statistics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/337069)
- *Topological insulators*: [Book recommendations - Topological Insulators for dummies](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/424581)
- *Iron-based superconductors*: [Reference needed for Iron-based superconductors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28300)
- *Soft matter*: [Soft Condensed Matter book for self-study](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/225490)
- *Intermolecular forces*: [Resource for intermolecular forces in soft condensed matter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5347)
- *Materials science*: [Best Materials Science Introduction Book?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31626)
- *Quantum chemistry*: [Is there any quantum physics book that treats covalent bonding systematically?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/531859)

**Particle Physics**

- *Popular*: [Good book about elementary particles for high school students?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9389)
- *General*: [Books for particle physics and the Standard Model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312)
- *Experimental*: [Enlightening experimental physics books/resources](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22038)
- *Detectors*: [Reference for solid state particle detector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11434)
- *Data analysis*: [Textbook about the handiwork of a HEP analysis?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89238)
- *Heavy ion collisions*: [Reference on stages of heavy ion collisions in particle physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148375)
- *Theories of everything*: [What is a good non-technical introduction to theories of everything?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38399)

**Quantum Field Theory**

- *Background*: [Textbook on group theory to be able to start QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23387)
- *Basics*: [A No-Nonsense Introduction to Quantum Field Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11878)
- *Relativistic QM*: [Any suggestion for a book that includes quantum mechanics principles and smoothly introduces you to QED (quantum electrodynamics)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213136/)
- *Introductory*: [What is a complete book for introductory quantum field theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441)
- *Lectures*: [Online QFT video lectures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10021)
- *S-matrix theory*: [Materials about S-matrix and S-matrix theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105138)
- *Renormalization*: [Are there books on Regularization and Renormalization in QFT at an Introductory level?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12385)
- *Renormalization (in general)*: [Suggested reading for renormalization (not only in QFT)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/743)
- *For mathematicians*: [Quantum Field Theory from a mathematical point of view](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27700)
- *Rigorous/axiomatic*: [Rigorous approaches to quantum field theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/49757)
- *Algebraic QFT*: [Which are some best sources to learn Algebraic Quantum Field Theory (AQFT)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/227450)
- *Topological field theory*: [Reading list in topological QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41589)
- *Nonperturbative*: [Books on non-perturbative phenomena in quantum field theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/367793)
- *Curved spacetime*: [Suggested reading for quantum field theory in curved spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110763)
- *Curved spacetime (advanced)*: [Modern treatment of effective QFT in curved spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373527)

**General Relativity**

- *Introductory*: [Books for general relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363)
- *Mathematical*: [Mathematically-oriented Treatment of General Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15002)
- *Exercises*: [Recommendation on books with problems for general relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164325)
- *Exact solutions*: [A book containing a large subset of known exact solutions to the EFEs](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221191)

**High Energy Theory**

- *String theory (introductory)*: [Introduction to string theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29007)
- *String theory (advanced)*: [Advanced topics in string theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27760)
- *String theory (matrix)*: [Good introductory text for matrix string theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6424)
- *Supersymmetry (with exercises)*: [Problems book recommendation on supersymmetry, supergravity and superstring theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/120150)
- *Kahler manifolds*: [Kähler and complex manifolds](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92776)
- *Conformal field theory*: [Reading list and book recommendation on Conformal Field Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149468)
- *Conformal bootstrap*: [Looking for intro to Conformal Bootstrap](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172180)
- *AdS/CFT*: [Introduction to AdS/CFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36303)
- *Integrability*: [What is a good introduction to integrable models in physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26912)
- *Entanglement entropy*: [Quantum field theory text on entanglement entropy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228127)
- *Twistors*: [Gentle introduction to twistors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36359)
- *Loop quantum gravity*: [LQG Demystified Book?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15803)
- *Quantum Gravity in general*: [Obligated Bibliography for Quantum Gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/692392/)

**Miscellaneous**

- *Free*: [List of freely available physics books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6157)
- *Lecture notes*: [Best Sets of Physics Lecture Notes and Articles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101187)
- *Historical*: [Physics history book with some math](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18227)
- *Acoustics*: [Books about musical acoustics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194834)
- *Chemistry*: [Where should a physicist go to learn chemistry?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6208)
- *Biophysics*: [What are good references for learning about Biophysics at graduate level?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221417)
- *Computational*: [Textbook recommendation for computational physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161368)
- *Experimental*: [What's a good book on experimental methods for physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/399557)
- *Plasma physics*: [Book suggestion for introductory plasma physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192175)

**Problems**

- *Olympiad*: [Best physics olympiad resources](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22696)
- *Graduate exams*: [Graduate Physics Problems Books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10325)
- *Puzzles site*: [Is there a physics Puzzles site like Project Euler?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20832/)